# Convert string to datetime using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net textbox which also works with jquery datepicker.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxFirstReceivedDate" CssClass="selectstyle" runat="server" MaxLength="100" fieldtype='date' Width="200"></asp:TextBox>

$(function () {
        $('input[fieldtype="date"]').datepicker({ firstDay: 1
                                                , changeMonth: true
                                                , changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

The user might enter a date in RFC format like "Sun 17/08/2014 9:43 AM" or from the datepicker.

I want to convert this entered string into a proper date format (ex., 17/08/2014 9:43:00 AM) when the user leaves the textbox (maybe onblur event).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to use ajax calendar extender which will gave you much more flexibility than date picker.Download ajax controls for visual studio and add them to visual studio, then drag drop calendar extender. It will also gave you the desired result which u want.